# Find lambdas so that two polynomials share a root and find such root

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find $ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} $ such that the following polynomials share a root, and find that root.

$$ \lambda x^3-x^2 - x - (\lambda + 1) \quad and \quad \lambda x^2 - x - (\lambda +1)   $$

I tried dividing them both by $ (x-r) $, where r is my root. Then I want the remainder of that division to be 0. That gives two equations and two unknowns, which should be solvable, but I can't get my self to get it right. And, besides, there *must* be a better method: this was part of an exam, and this approach would simply take too much time.

Any ideas?

Comment: If $f,g\in \mathbb F[x]$ have the common root $\alpha$, then for every $p,q\in \mathbb F[x]$ the polynomial $pf+qg$ has this root.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The polynomials factor respectively as $$(x^2 + x + 1) [\lambda x + (-\lambda - 1)]$$ and $$(x + 1) [\lambda x + (-\lambda - 1)] .$$ (In particular, for most values of $\lambda$ they have a common linear factor and hence a common root.)

More generally, one can detect whether two polynomials have a common root (possibly in some field extension) using the resultant, which is given by the determinant of the [Sylvester Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) for the two polynomials. (Even the size of this matrix depends on the degree of the polynomials, so if we use this method again we must treat the case $\lambda = 0$ separately.)

Comment: +1 from me, I do not see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is a common root, then $$0=λr^3-r^2-r-(λ+1)-(λr^2-r-(λ+1))=λr^3-(λ+1)r^2$$ So, for example for $λ=-1$ they share the root $r=0$ (actually this solution can be found directly by inspection, since the constant terms disappear). For $λ\neq 0$ and $r\neq0$ there are other solutions, since then $$0=λr-(λ+1) \implies r=\frac{λ+1}{λ}=1+\frac1λ$$ is a common root.

Comment: You can not take $\lambda=0$

Comment: @hamidkamali Firstly, why not? Secondly, $λ=0$ is only one case from the many that I treat. For $λ\neq 0$ I give a parametric solution that works, but obviously you missed it.

Comment: If $\lambda=0$ we get that $x^2+x+1$ and $x+1$ have common root which is trivialy wrong.

Comment: @hamidkamali Yes, correct I miscalculated that. I corrected it.